# How to parameterise concourse task files

Tags: concourse

I'm pretty impressed by the power and simplicity of Concourse. Since my pipelines keep growing I decided to move the tasks to separate files. One of the tasks use a custom Docker image from our own private registry. So, in that task file I have:

```
image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: docker.mycomp.com:443/app-builder
    tag: latest
    username: {{dckr-user}}
    password: {{dckr-pass}}
```

When I do a set-pipeline, I pass the --load-from-vars argument to load credentials etc from a seperate file.

Now here's my problem: I notice that the vars in my pipeline files are replaced with the actual correct values, but once the task runs, the afore mentioned {{dckr-user}} and {{dckr-pass}} are not replaced.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: check https://concourseci.slack.com/archives/general/p1488384207016956 for the discussion about this topic on Slack

Comment: This is soon to come. It has been merged into `Master` on the Concourse GitHub repo. See > https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/454 ...

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what was provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42792856/7179936)

If specifically you are looking to use private images in a task, you can do the following in your `pipeline.yml`:

```
resources:
- name: some-private-image
  type: docker
  params:
    repository: ...
    username: {{my-username}}
    password: {{my-password}}

jobs:
- name: foo
  plan:
  - get: some-private-image
  - task: some-task
    image: some-private-image
```

Because this is your pipeline, you can use `--load-vars-from`, which will first `get` your image as a resource and then use it for the subsequent task.

You can also see this [article on pre-fetching ruby gems in test containers on Concourse](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/concourse-docker-image-resource-cache-tutorial/)

The only downside to this is you cannot use this technique when running a `fly execute`.

Comment: the problem that I have with that solution is that the pipeline needs to know, which image a task requires - I would rather see that in the configuration of the task, not in the pipeline. This is not possible if you need any parameters in the task.yml and that is a flaw in the design of the pipeline / task concept in my eyes. It breaks the possibility of having tasks in a generic library, hence avoids re-use of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

As of [concourse v3.3.0](https://concourse-ci.org/downloads.html#v3.3.0), you can set up [Credential Management](https://concourse-ci.org/creds.html) in order to use variables from one of the supported credential managers which are currently [Vault](https://vaultproject.io/), [Credhub](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/credhub), [Amazon SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html), and [Amazon Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html). So you don't have to separate your task files partially in the `pipeline.yml` anymore. The values you set in the Vault will be also accessible from the `task.yml` files.

And since v3.2.0 `{{foo}}` is deprecated in favor of `((foo))`.

Using the Credential Manager you can parameterize:

- `source` under resources in a `pipeline`
- `source` under resource_types in a `pipeline`
- `webhook_token` under resources in a `pipeline`
- `image_resource.source` under image_resource in a `task config`
- `params` in a `pipeline`
- `params` in a `task config`

For setting up vault with concourse you can refer to:

> https://concourse-ci.org/creds.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always define tasks in a pipeline.yml...
For example:

```
jobs:
- name: dotpersecond
  plan:
  - task: dotpersecond
    config:
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: docker.mycomp.com:443/app-builder
          tag: latest
          username: {{dckr-user}}
          password: {{dckr-pass}}
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
          - "-c"
          - |
            for i in `seq 1000`; do echo hi; sleep 2; done
```